# Does Winds of Abandon, overloaded, cause the player to search their library multiple times or just once?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I cast [Winds of Abandon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Winds%20of%20Abandon) for its overload cost which says,

> Exile each creature you don't control. For each creature exiled this way, its controller searches his or her library for a basic land card. Those players put those cards onto the battlefield tapped, then shuffle their libraries.

and an opponent has 5 creatures, does that opponent search their library five times for 1 basic land or search once for 5 basic lands?

Comment: Is there a reason the distinction matters to you?

Comment: @John this makes a difference when the owner of Winds of Abandon also controls an Opposition Agent for example.

Comment: @bautista I am not seeing why this matters for Opposition Agent.

Comment: @John you're right! Aven Mindcensor works as an example though.

Comment: @John I had a Winds of Abandon and Ob Nixilis, Unshackled combo in mind; thinking Ob would ping someone for like 50 dmg

Answer (score 13):

Just once - multiple searches that occur before shuffling are treated as a single search.

> **701.19h** An effect may instruct a player to search a library for one or more cards more than once before instructing a player to shuffle that library. This is the same as a single instruction for that player to search that library for all those cards. The player searches that library only once.

Since Winds of Abandon instructs the player to potentially search their library multiple times for a basic land and *then* shuffle, it should be treated as searching the library once for multiple basic lands.